# Word for a ballad about a hero

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means a ballad that is specifically about a hero. I know an epic is a super long poem about a hero and doesn't necessarily have a set meter. A ballad is a song-like poem that has a set rhyme scheme and meter (usually), but doesn't imply a heroic topic. I need a combination of those words: a ballad that is about a hero. I can't find any word that fits what I need, can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: I only can explain it in music right now :-)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_(Beethoven)

Heroic Balade ?

Comment: Planxty? A melodic harp tune, often in tribute to a named individual: ""Planxty Irwin," for example, would be in honor of Colonel John Irwin of Sligo" per en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planxty

Comment: Paean: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/paean is kind of close...

Comment: In ancient literature we have the _Epic of Gilgamesh_, the _Epic of Erra_, the _Epic of Zimri-Lim_ etc. All cases use the word 'epic' in reference to a hero so I don't see any other word. Maybe opera? Heroic opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ballad about a hero?  Not a single word, but I think you could call it **a saga ballad**.

> - **saga** - was originally used to describe Icelandic prose narratives composed in the 12th and 13th centuries. The word first appeared in English in that sense during the 18th century; by the middle of the 19th century we were employing saga in a somewhat looser fashion, in reference to modern stories involving heroic deeds that bore some resemblance to the Icelandic tales of yore. By the 20th century saga had come to be applied to other written works, typically a novel or series of novels, especially those that took place over a significant period of time. [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saga)

Examples from the web:

- "an effective **saga ballad** about President Kennedy's heroic exploits during World War II."
- "...conversely, some ballad romances (ro- manviser) have the multiepisodic narratives of the **saga ballad** with the mimetic style and romantic ..."
- "Marty Robbins wrote **a saga ballad** called "El Paso" that showed..."
- "Roll Up Your Sleeves is **a saga ballad** about a man and his fickle girl."

Another option might be **"a hymn of praise"**, but still not a single word.

> **"paean"** as mentioned in a comment, is a single word and means 
>   **"any song of praise, joy, thanksgiving, or triumph.** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/paean)

Comment: I'm looking for _a word_ that means a ballad that is specifically about a hero.... I need a combination of those words: a ballad that is about a hero. single-word-requests

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a term exists as a single word. There are plenty of Google hits for a ***Hero ballad*** or ***Hero song*** as a two-word phrase, but nothing that is a single word term.

A plausible adaptation of a single word term that might fit what you're looking for is, for example, ***memoir***.

Memoir tends to refer to a biographical history or form of storytelling that relates someone's life events as they recall them. Often they are in a novel or poem form, but sometimes a composer may either set a memoir poem to song, or else write an aural memoir (such as a piano piece in the ballad form, titled ***memoir*** as a style-piece). This can be true of a hero's deeds being told in a ballad. Memoirs, however, typically are, allegedly, autobiographical in nature. Therefore, in the vein of folklore, it must be something that has been passed down from the source of origin (meaning, the Hero himself) to become song.

Comment: I have to agree that there's no single word for a 'ballad in praise of a hero' ... paean (as mentioned above) might be closest. Other options could be 'panegyric ballad', 'sung encomium', and so on.